# How to speed up starting of wayland-gnome session?

Tags: fedora, gnome, wayland

On my upgraded Fedora 25 system, I encounter a problem when logging in with my main user identity: it takes literally 2-4 minutes to start (i.e. to get me into the gnome shell).
Logging in as other users (that basically have not customised their gnome shells), takes only a few seconds.

Disabling gnome extensions does not make a difference.

Logging in as the main user with the gnome x legacy session (x org) takes only a few seconds (as before upgrading).

Sorry, this is not yet a fully formed question. (please help)

One starting question is: which log files (etc) could I investigate?

Another question: what immediate actions could I take to speed wayland starting up?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

SELinux is an important part of security. You should try `F1` to read the boot sequence during boot and your `/var/log/messages` to be sure it comes from SELinx and if yes how to enable SELinux on some part of your system to keep it safe.